# VS Code cannot activate virtual environment with env\Scripts\activate.bat

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, terminal, environment-variables, virtualenv

I've been looking at all sorts of sources and I cannot make it happen that a virtual environment is created. I have serious problems with the Terminal. Whereas in the other sources by just typing the commands as instructed like `\env\Scripts\activate.bat` works perfectly, for me I just get an error saying it is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet nor a function nor a script file nor an executable program, see screenshot. It's a nightmare. I also e.g. changed the settings.json as in some suggested methods, but no luck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoL1D.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the virtual environment Scripts folder there are 2 activate scripts:  `activate.bat` and `activate.ps1`.
`.bat` files aren't recognized in the terminal.
Try running just `env\Scripts\activate`.

Comment: Yup, I already solved it. I did .\env\Scripts\activate.ps1
Yours works as well though